# How to deploy jar dependencies (native dlls) on spark workers in Azure Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jna, databricks

I am writing a Java wrapper `TnHandler.java` that uses JNA, and calls `mycustom.so` native library, it has other dependency files. I export my java app as runnable jar and installed in Azure data bricks cluster.

In PySpark I call my jar like this in PyPark notebook in Databricks

```py
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
java_import(sc._gateway.jvm,"")

jvm = sc._gateway.jvm
java_import(jvm, "*")

foo = jvm.TnHandler()
def applyTn(s):
  return foo.dummyTn(s)

applyTn("give me $20")`
```

I keep getting this error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'mycustom.so':
libmycustom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I think the reason is `.so` file and all of its dependencies are not present in worker node where code is being executed.

How do I ensure that desired `.so` and all of its dependencies are found in class path of which ever node the code is being executed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNA relies on LD-Library-Path environment variable, to search for the libraries that you are trying to load.

I solved the problem by setting LD_Library_Path environment variable in my cluster settings

Comment: Glad to know that issue has been resolved and thanks for sharing the solution.  This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.